# Call fallback function from eth-brownie from proxy

Tags: web3.py, python, delegatecall, proxy-contracts, brownie

I have a contract that has a fallback function to `delegatecall` all function calls to a different contract. I can't seem to use my typical API to interact with the contract it delegates a call to.

I have a contract called `Box.sol` with a `retrieve` function. My `TransparentUpgradeableProxy` `proxy` contract delegates all calls to that contract. However, if I call `retrieve` on the proxy contract, I get:

```
AttributeError: Contract 'TransparentUpgradeableProxy' object has no attribute 'retrieve'
```

Here is how the code should look

```py
from brownie import Box, TransparentUpgradeableProxy

account = accounts[0]
print(f"Deploying to {network.show_active()}")
box = Box[len(Box) - 1]
proxy = TransparentUpgradeableProxy[len(TransparentUpgradeableProxy) - 1]
print(proxy.retrieve())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use

1. The actual ABI of the implementation instead of the ABI file of the proxy contract
2. Address of the proxy contract

```py
from brownie import Box, TransparentUpgradeableProxy, Contract

account = accounts[0]
proxy = TransparentUpgradeableProxy[-1]
proxy_box = Contract.from_abi("Box", proxy.address, Box.abi)
print(proxy_box.retrieve())
```

Answer (score 2):

I found today another way to do it which is very convenient especially when fetching contracts from explorer and you don't want to bother importing its ABI.

In your case you could use:

```
proxy_box = Contract.from_explorer(TransparentUpgradeableProxy.address,
                                   as_proxy_for=Box.address)
print(proxy_box.retrieve())
```

Brownie doc about it: https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api-network.html?highlight=from_explorer#brownie.network.account.Account